# Как сделать пропорциональное расширение блока Image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Хочу сделать чтобы фотография отображалась квадратом, а именно высота равна ширине экрана. Как это можно сделать в XAML? Пробовал сделать так:

```
<Image Name="Im" Height="{Binding ElementName=Im, Path=Width}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

Но что-то в этой записи не так, тк UWP меня игнорирует...

Comment: `Stretch="Uniform"` или там `Stretch="UniformToFill"`?

Comment: И что значит «игнорирует»? Покажите ожидаемый эффект и реальный вид.

Comment: ... Path=ActualWidth ...

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на свойство Stretch. Установите его, соответственно нужному поведению(растянуть и пр). 
Что касается размера, то конструкция подобного типа работать будет, если установлен сам Width.